# How to specify QComboBox items at runtime?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog I've designed graphically in Qt Designer. It has some QComboBox that I'd like to put some placeholder text in at design time, and then load the actual contents at runtime.

Of course, I can let the QComboBox get created and then call clear(), addItem() to override the list. But what if this QComboBox appears in several places? What's the best way to stay DRY?

I thought the logical way would be to subclass QComboBox and set the contents in the constructor and promote the widget in Qt Designer to my subclass. Unfortunately, uic calls the constructor just fine but then shortly afterwards calls retranslateUi(), which replaces the contents with the design time entries.

I like the subclass idea because it will also allow me to abstract the behaviour when the combobox selection is changed, but I can't see a way to ensure my dynamic contents will take effect.

Example subclass constructor:

```
Sub_QComboBox::Sub_QComboBox(QWidget * parent) : QComboBox(parent)
{
    QStringList entries = getEntryList();
    clear();
    for(int i=0; i<entries.size(); ++i)
        addItem(entries[i], getDataForEntry(i));
}
```

Resulting ui_dialog.h produced by uic:

```
void setupUi(QDialog *Dialog)
{
    //<snip>

    cbxMyComboBox = new Sub_QComboBox(parent);

    //<snip>

    retranslateUi(Dialog);

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Dialog);
} // setupUi

void retranslateUi(QDialog *Dialog)
{
    //<snip>

    cbxLanguage->clear();
    cbxLanguage->insertItems(0, QStringList()
    //design time contents
    );

    //<snip>

} // retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using is as follows. I decided there's no need to resort to a custom model when the built-in one is fine.

First, population of contents is moved out of the constructor and into a dedicated, public method:

```
void Sub_QComboBox::populateContents(void)
{
    QStringList entries = getEntryList();
    clear();
    for(int i=0; i<entries.size(); ++i)
        addItem(entries[i], getDataForEntry(i));
}
```

Then, I call that in my dialog constructor:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ui.mySub_QComboBox->populateContents();
}
```

And finally, also call it from the dialog's changeEvent, which needs to be implemented anyway to catch a language change:

```
void Dialog::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QDialog::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type())
    {
        case QEvent::LanguageChange:
            ui.retranslateUi(this); //can't believe we have to do this manually for every QWidget subclass we write...
            ui.mySub_QComboBox->populateContents();
            break;
        default:
            break;
   }
}
```

Done! So I can put whatever I like in Qt Designer so it looks nice for screenshots/demos, but at run time the contents are set once on construction and again if the language changes.

Comment: Ouch, 2 down votes for answering my own question in the way that optimally solves my problem. Very curious to know what I've done wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use models with QComboBox, so that way whenever you want to change the contents of the combobox you only need to update the model and the rest of comboboxes will be automatically updated.

> It has some QComboBox that I'd like to put some placeholder text in at
>   design time

**QComboBox** does not have a placeholder option so you need to have a editable combobox and use this:

```
myCombo->lineEdit()->setPlaceholderText("Some text");
```

> load the actual contents at runtime

to load contents dynamically you can use models.

```
itemModel = new QStringListModel(this);
comboBox1->setModel(itemModel);
comboBox2->setModel(itemModel);
```

Comment: I was concerned models might be suggested. I'm not sure it's worth the effort to write a custom model that has a QString/QVariant pair for each row given that the list is only set once on initialisation (excluding translations).

Comment: In models you  only need to set the contents of the combobox at one place and it would be reflected in all the comboboxs at the same time.
Otherwise you will need to set the same contents for multiple combos as you mentioned.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I've subclassed QComboBox. The population happens once in the constructor for each instance. No problems there. The problem is it is subsequently overwritten. I understand what models do. I'd still need a custom derivative. And perhaps I misused "placeholder" - I meant the design-time contents of the QComboBox.

Comment: If you dont want to use models you could alternatively create a json object, and use it with combobox.